# Case sensitive problem in Excel’s pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Example below, the ID of people are case sensitive (if don’t consider the case, some of them are of the same, for example, David’s and Mike’s, Lilly’s and John’s).

When putting them into a pivot table, it displays the same IDs for different people, i.e. David’s = Mike’s, Lilly’s = John’s.

Is there a way to have the pivot table to display actual IDs (case sensitive)?

```
ID  Name
Txze    David
TxZe    Mike
TwgQ    Lucy
3RqM    Lilly
3RQm    John
TvrE    Kate
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried writing your own formulae using index() with match()?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, had a quick go with index() and match() as suggested in my comment:

```
INDEX(A$2:A$7,MATCH(D2,$B$2:$B$7,0))
```

[image]

D2 and D4 contain the Name looked for and the results are in F2 & F4, which give the different results. Note, 0 is used for an exact match in the match function.